# Requesting User Input to Name the File being created using ofstream C++ MFC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc

How would you go about giving the user the ability to change the Name of the ofstream File using c++ MFC.  I would like to add an Edit Control Box that will give the user an ability to Type in the File Name before clicking save. This is my current code, any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

```
void CECET_MFC_Dialog_Based_IntroDlg::OnBnClickedSave()
    {
    UpdateData(true);

    ofstream myfile ("Save_Random.xls");
    if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    myfile << "This is the 1st line.\n" << endl;

    for(int index=0; index<100; index++){   // samples to create
     myfile << setprecision(4) << dblArray[index] << endl;
    }

    myfile << "This is another line.\n";
    myfile << "Max  = " << rndMax << endl;
    myfile << "Min  = " << rndMin << endl;
    myfile << "Mean = " << Final_Avg << endl;
    myfile.close();
  }
    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    UpdateData(false);  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the edit control just like you would any other -- drag it from the toolbox into your dialog. Perhaps more importantly, you normally want to put a browse button next to it, so the user can browse for the folder/file name they want. Code for that button looks something like this:

```
void CYourDlg::OnBrowseButton() {
    UpdateData();

    CFileDialog dlg(false, NULL, NULL, OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT );

    if (dlg.DoModal())
        m_dest_file = dlg.GetPathName();
    UpdateData(false);
}
```

Then, when the user clicks whatever button (or menu entry, etc.) to have you write to the file, you do something like this:

```
std::ofstream myfile(m_dest_file);
// write the data
```

I've assumed that you've associated the edit control with a `CString` named `m_dest_file`. Obviously you can pick a name of your choice, but (of course) you need to use the same name both places.